# PHP - MySql creaing multiple entries

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a site where you login with steam and if your steam ID is already in our DB, it adds you, else, nothing happens. Here is my current code:

```
    $conn = mysql_connect('', '', '');
    mysql_select_db('');
    $result = mysql_query($sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE steamid=$value LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        global $value;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`steamid`) VALUES ($value)");
    }
```

This works and adds the ID but it will add it no mater what, even if it is already recorded.. So ever time the user logs in, It creates a new entry in the table, Which mysql_num_rows should be stopping.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I am not entering lots of values and removing duplicates, It adds a new entry even if a previous value is recorded, which mysql_num_rows should prevent, but its not.

Comment: your query is wrong `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid=$value LIMIT 1");`

Comment: Still creates the same result.

Comment: add error checking, and stop using mysql_*

Comment: MySqli confuses me, but it is on the to-do list.